# En qué casos se utilizan los tipos de desviación estándar "SD" y "MR" al hacer una carta de control x one con el paquete qcc

Tags: r, rstudio, proceso, estadística

Se me ha hecho confuso entender eso ya que, si bien en el manual del paquete qcc se da una explicación, esta me ha resultado complicada y la verdad no sé en qué casos se debe utilizar un tipo de desviación. Agradecería mucho la ayuda proporcionana. De antemando expongo el código de ejemplo que se encuentra en el manual qcc.

```
# Water content of antifreeze data (Wetherill and Brown, 1991, p. 120)
x <- c(2.23, 2.53, 2.62, 2.63, 2.58, 2.44, 2.49, 2.34, 2.95, 2.54, 2.60, 2.45,
       2.17, 2.58, 2.57, 2.44, 2.38, 2.23, 2.23, 2.54, 2.66, 2.84, 2.81, 2.39,
       2.56, 2.70, 3.00, 2.81, 2.77, 2.89, 2.54, 2.98, 2.35, 2.53)
# the Shewhart control chart for one-at-time data
# 1) using MR (default)
qcc(x, type="xbar.one", data.name="Water content (in ppm) of batches of antifreeze")
# 2) using SD
qcc(x, type="xbar.one", std.dev = "SD", data.name="Water content (in ppm) of batches of antifreeze")`
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: es cierto, el paquete no dice nada sobre que método usar para calcular la desviación y en que casos, pero tampoco es algo que se le pueda pedir a la documentación, es más bien un tema de dominio, tampoco parece un problema apropiado para el sitio (programación),  te sugiero que intentes en https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque parece estar más relacionada con la estadística que con la programación.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo ya que este tema parece ir más allá del lenguaje R. De antemano le agradezco mucho por su colaboración.